# Sending HTTP POST request with custom JSON file in the request body

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I'm facing with some issue in my java code:

```
package com.automation.com.automation.<name>;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.junit.Test;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class SendDCandidateDate {

    @Test
    public void sendCandidateData() throws FileNotFoundException {


        String accessToken = "<your access token comes here>";
        String apiUrl = "<your API url comes here>";

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            try {
                Object object = parser.parse(new     FileReader("src/main/resources/Full_List.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
            given().auth().preemptive().oauth2(accessToken);
            given().body(jsonObject).when().post(apiUrl).then().assertThat().statusCode(200);

        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no exception, however the assertion comes back with error 404 instead of 200. (Error 401 is also acceptable for now, which means the accessToken is expired it would be also an expected behaviour).

I think I have a logical issue in my code, can anyone help me with it?

Comment: ` String apiUrl = "<your API url comes here>";` This is not a valid URL, therefore you'll get a 404 (not found) error.

Comment: @AlanTuning - No. I'm pretty sure OP was simply hiding the actual values here. This would throw an Invalid URI exception or Host not found type error long before a request would even go out.

Comment: In any case, a 404 wouldn't cause me to look at my code right away. It's more likely that the url is wrong or there is no connection to that url.

Comment: @rmlan, you are right, I have a valid URL there, I guess it is good. I created the whole project in SoapUI and it is working fine, I just want to make it work in java code as well. FYI: others

Comment: Did you take a look at wireshark traces? To be sure you send data you wish to send.

Comment: Actually I tried with Fiddler and it seems that not activity is happening. How could that be?

Comment: @kiiper Accrding to docs https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#serialization RestAssured have support for Jackson & GSon, not json-simple. But you try to set some object framework doesn't understand (doesn't know how to serialize it). So I think if you need to specify body as json, just read it to string and put as your body.

Comment: @stborod, thanks, I'll look into it as soon I have some time, thanks!